# Exception in StringConcatFactory - Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

While learning java9 `StringConcatFactory` class I am unable to understand why following code with  `MethodHandles.publicLookup()` throws  `StringConcatException` exception while if `MethodHandles.lookup()` is used everything is working fine.

As per java docs of lookup:

> "lookup - Represents a lookup context with the accessibility
>   privileges of the caller"

```
StringConcatFactory.makeConcat(MethodHandles.publicLookup(),
"abc",MethodType.methodType(String.class));//Exception Here


StringConcatFactory.makeConcat(MethodHandles.lookup(), 
"abc", MethodType.methodType(String.class)); //Working fine
```

I am not sure where I am mistaken? Please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: java9 is beta Status. please ask at Oracle if this is a bug

Comment: As my answer indicates: you probably want to put up a [mcve]. You should at least provide the exception stack trace here.

Comment: what is `concatType` for your code? and what exception do you get?

Comment: “throws exception” is quite a thin problem description. I suppose, the exception has a specific type, maybe a stack trace and perhaps even a message…

Comment: You must update the concatType definition as well. It seems strange why for different Methodhandles the makeConcat would throw that exception. Also the stacktrace of the exception is always helpful to look at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc for `makeConcat` says about the first parameter:

> **lookup** Represents a lookup context with the accessibility privileges of the caller

The lookup context returned by `publicLookup` does not have those privileges.

Even if you concatenate nothing, the exception will still be thrown:

```
MethodType concatType = MethodType.methodType(String.class); // No arguments, returns String
StringConcatFactory.makeConcat(MethodHandles.publicLookup(), "abc", concatType); // Exception
```

Because the access privileges of the context are checked in `StringConcatFactory#doStringConcat`:

```
if ((lookup.lookupModes() & MethodHandles.Lookup.PRIVATE) == 0) {
    throw new StringConcatException("Invalid caller: " +
            lookup.lookupClass().getName());
}
```

The context needs a private lookup mode, and a `publicLookup` does not have it:

```
System.out.println((MethodHandles.publicLookup().lookupModes()
    & MethodHandles.Lookup.PRIVATE) != 0); // false
System.out.println((MethodHandles.lookup().lookupModes()
    & MethodHandles.Lookup.PRIVATE) != 0); // true
```

Answer (score 5):

The Javadoc for [`publicLookup()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#publicLookup--) says:

> Returns a lookup object which is trusted **minimally**.

versus [lookup()](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#lookup--):

> Returns a lookup object with full capabilities to emulate all supported bytecode behaviors of the caller. These capabilities include private access to the caller. Factory methods on the lookup object can create direct method handles for any member that the caller has access to via bytecodes, including protected and private fields and methods. This lookup object is a capability which may be delegated to trusted agents.

And the Javadoc for [`makeConcat()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.html#makeConcat-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) finally says:

> throws StringConcatException - If any of the linkage invariants described here are violated.

Given the fact that the question does *not* contain any more details, the most likely answer is: you have some sort of "permission" problem here. Maybe you try to "concat" something that simply isn't available when using "minimal trust".

Answer (score 3):

The primary reason as in your case when a `publicLookup` :

```
StringConcatFactory.makeConcat(MethodHandles.publicLookup(), "abc", MethodType.methodType(String.class));
```

can throw a [`StringConcatException`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/StringConcatException.html) while on the other hand, the `lookup`

```
StringConcatFactory.makeConcat(MethodHandles.lookup(), "abc", MethodType.methodType(String.class));
```

would work fine is when the method handle created are used to access private members of a class of a private class of a package.

As stated in the [Javadoc of publicLookup](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#publicLookup--) linked by @GhostCat as well

```
publicLookup => PUBLIC_LOOKUP => (PUBLIC|UNCONDITIONAL) modes
```

> Returns a lookup object which is trusted minimally. The lookup has the
>   `PUBLIC` and `UNCONDITIONAL modes`. ***It can only be used to create method
>   handles to public members of public classes in packages that are
>   exported unconditionally.***

while for a [lookup](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#lookup--)

```
lookup => (lookupClass => Reflection.getCallerClass, FULL_POWER_MODES  => (ALL_MODES & ~UNCONDITIONAL))
```

> Returns a lookup object with full capabilities to emulate all
>   supported bytecode behaviors of the caller. These capabilities include
>   private access to the caller. Factory methods on the lookup object can
>   create direct method handles for any member that the caller has access
>   to via bytecodes, including protected and private fields and methods.
>   This lookup object is a capability which may be delegated to trusted
>   agents.
>
> Do not store it in place where untrusted code can access it.
>   This method is caller sensitive, which means that it may return
>   different values to different callers.
>
> For any given caller class C, the lookup object returned by this call
>   has equivalent capabilities to any lookup object supplied by the JVM
>   to the bootstrap method of an invokedynamic instruction executing in
>   the same caller class C.